# Preserving the radiobutton values using cookies

Tags: javascript

I have three radio buttons 
I want to preserve the radio button values after the browser refresh using cookies.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a "onchange" event handler to you radio buttons and save the new value into a cookie.
Then attach a "onload" event handler to your body and set the values of radio buttons based on the value in the cookie (if it is present) ...

Comment: are you asking for a complete code example? Because I don't know how I could be more brief than that what I have written above.

Comment: yes i need complete code example
or should i provide u with my code can u make the changes in it